# How to find the number of Distinct Submatrices?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to solve problem [DSUBMTR](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DSUBMTR/) from spoj which asks to count distinct sub-matrices of given matrix. I tried using hash-tables (STL MAP), but the approach is O(N<sup>2</sup>M<sup>2</sup>lg(NM)) and hence times out. Note that given matrix consists of only alphabets.

I'd like to have a few hints/pointers to how such problems may be solved.

Comment: Probably some sort of partitioning. For example, find the equal a*b submatrices, then for each group of equal submatrices you only need to compare an extra column to get the groups of equal a*(b+1) submatrices. Given the sizes of the groups, it's easy to count the number of distinct submatrices.

Comment: Please give me a few hints on implementation, as I had this idea too, but my implementation does not have a better time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a very good *food for thought thing*. What I had in my mind is to use the ASCII value of the sub-matrices' alphabets and arrange their vales in such a way that only a unique value can be generated for that particular sub-matrix. For instance, if the matrix is [(A,B,C);(A,A,A)], then for the sub-matrix [(A,B);(A,A)] you can use the `ASCII(A)*1000000000+ASCII(B)*1000000+ASCII(A)*1000+ASCII(A)` as a unique value for this particular `4 X 4` sub-matrix (It is though not a proper formula but I hope you can think of a more proper mathematical approach). So, now you can hash them into a hashtable. Apply this formula for all the sub-matrix and see the collisions on the hashtable and neglect the repeated ones. Then count the number of filled-in positions in the hashtables.

Comment: Can you suggest a better scheme, as the dimensions are upto 128 and the scheme you suggested is not expendable upto that extent.

Comment: @Algotest since there exists only 26 × 2 alphabets, so you can use their corresponding values of two digits to generate a unique value of the sub-matrices. As you have to compare only sub-matrices with same length × width, you will have different values for distinct sub-matrices. Do this for all the possible sizes of the sub-matrices.

Comment: There will be 128 × 128 sub-matrices. I'm not understanding how will you generate a unique id for each. If possible please add a code snippet.

Comment: Don't worry about the different/unique values for all those 128×128 matrices. Value should be compared with sub-matrices with same length × width. Different sized sub-matrices will obviously be different. I will try writing the codes in some free time since the code wasn't asked, only the approach.